# My model's field are not showing in admin panels

Tags: python, django

My models are not showing in admin panel.
My models.py

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE),
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE),
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1),

    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.id)
```

admin.py:

```
@admin.register(Cart)
class CartModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'user', 'product', 'quantity']
```

I had also tried this:

```
admin.site.register(Cart)
```

[image]

Comment: Is app that has Cart model in settings, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#discovery-of-admin-files

Comment: yes it has app in settings.py

Comment: both should work, are you sure you've ran the makemigrations/migrate command ? also, did you import the Cart model inside admin.py ?

Comment: yes sir I have uploaded this

Comment: sir check i have updated an image

Comment: thanks, check my answer :)

Comment: You seem to have added commas to your field atrributes, python does not use commas in that way, also admin panel shows your model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove all the comma's(,) from you model and make the migration again. Then the fields will show up in the admin panel.

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.id)
```